# Highlighting Rows by Grouping ID based on Categorical Pairs

Tags: python, excel, tableau-api

I'm looking at a way of highlighting rows in a table, grouped by customer ID.

By grouping the customer ID, I am able to see which options the customer picked in column D

But I am only interested in highlighting customers who picked budgeting by itself so I could possibly delete them from the database

[image]

How would I do this? Open to solutions in excel, tableau and python. Table is currently in Excel format - data was originally exported from tableau.

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve your need with the provided answer?

Answer (score 1):

If your purpouse is just to highlight rows having the same value for a specific column, you only need an highlight action.

Once your worksheet/dashboard is ready, go to worksheet/dashboard menu and select Actions --> highlight.

There, you may want to select your source and target worksheet and the field you are going to use as "highlighter".

Here's a quick example using the Superstore (and Category field):

[image]

The final result should be omething like this:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution @Fabio.  This was a new thing to learn for me.

Comment: it's quite simple too, isn't it?

Comment: O yes! But as it is said necessity is the mother of invention, and such need was never felt.  That's why i was not aware of this highlight feature

Comment: Ok thank you for the solution @Fabio. Will try it out

Comment: If the solution provided solves your need, please accept the answer in order to "close" this thread